# Multi tenant application - AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-tenant, sharding, rds

I am developing a multi tenant application that will support around 4 to 10 tenants. I would like to use the same database for all tenants, just setting a tenant id for each of them.
But as far as I know, AWS RDS doesn't support sharding (horizontal scaling).

Is there any other option? Actually we are maintaning one database per tenant, and it's too much effort.

Comment: You can use the Azure Shard Map to actually create multiple shards for each tenant and then have the databases provisioned using RDS. In this way, you do not have to worry about the sharding. Does this help?

Comment: All my system is on AWS cloud. It's not a option.